# Enumerate samples of AudioBuffer?

Tags: ios, audio, signal-processing, audiotoolbox

I have an `AudioBuffer` from `AVCaptureSession` `CMSampleBuffer`, like:

```
Sample Rate:              44100 
Format ID:                 lpcm 
Format Flags:                 C 
Bytes per Packet:             2 
Frames per Packet:            1 
Bytes per Frame:              2 
Channels per Frame:           1 
Bits per Channel:            16 

kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger 
kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked 
kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger 
kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked 
kLinearPCMFormatFlagsSampleFractionShift 
kAppleLosslessFormatFlag_32BitSourceData
```

How can I properly cast / enumerate samples? (to do some processing)
To what type should I cast `mData` with the above configuration?

Am I parsing format flags right at all? The output above was made by https://gist.github.com/eppz/11272305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I parsed flags above, `kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger` seems the answer, having 16 bits per channel.

So far it goes like:

```
// Enumerate audio buffers (probably faceing a sole buffer handling mono PCM anyway).
for (int audioBufferIndex = 0; audioBufferIndex <= audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; audioBufferIndex++)
{
    AudioBuffer eachAudioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[audioBufferIndex];

    // Enumerate samples.
    SInt16 *samples;
    samples = (SInt16*)eachAudioBuffer.mData;
    for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex <= sampleCount; sampleIndex++)
    {
        SInt16 eachSample = samples[sampleIndex];
        printf("%i \n", eachSample);
    }
}
```